# syncing between phone and web algorithm

Tags: android, ios, windows, algorithm, web

i have a simple note application in two platform, One in mobile(Android & iOS) and other one is web based. I want that this two sync.

My problem is that: How i can determine that which version of a note(android or web) is newer and that text has to be sync? In fact, I need a sync algorithm. If i use timestamp, if users date time in his phone goes to wrong date time, syncing system throws to problem. I want newest edit syncs to all clients.

For example if mobile app were offline and make some changes, In the same time we made changes in server in the same note and when mobile App goes online, which of this changes should be kept? What is the solution?

In the end, What is the best method for this? I want to have best sync method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clients shouldn't use their local time. Only the server has the right time. Clients have timezone which they can use to show appropriate time to the user. Roughly speaking  sync algorithm could look like this:

1. Client A edits a `X note` and sends event(request) to the server that the note was updated.
2. The server receives event and updates timestamp of the message. Then it broadcasts new event that the `note X` was updated
3. Client B receives event (with updated note and timestamp) from server and shows to the user updated note with appropriate time.

Comment: if mobile app is offline and make some changes, In the same time we made changes in server in the same note and when mobile App goes online, which of this changes should be kept? What is the solution?

Comment: This is case when you need to implement `merge` mechanism on you server. And it's relatively complex thing. Basic idea is to store history of editing on the clients and send `the history` of changes but not just updated note. Then the server should compare histories of changes and make merge. There is no 100% working algorithms of merging and for instance even `Evernote` sometimes can't merge notes.